# how to get ansible inventory file name as a variable

Tags: jenkins, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have a situation where three Jenkins jobs running which uses ansible for the deployment. This jobs uses there own inventory files like /opt/abc/ci1.inventory, /opt/abc/ci2.inventory, /opt/abc/ci3.inventory etc. For example if first jenkins job is running it will use /opt/abc/ci1.inventory file.

I have a ansible template where I have one variable "jenkins_ci_job" which I want to assign a value according to the jenkins job running. For example if job 1 is running then it will assign the value "ci1" to "jenkins_ci_job" variable. The only way I see is to get the inventory file name and search if it contains the job name.

So I am searching for something like this

```
 jenkins_ci_job:
    "{{ 'ci1' if <ansible_inventory_full_path_name> contains 'ci1' else 'ci2' if <ansible_inventory_full_path_name> contains 'ci2 else 'ci3' }}"
```

Comment: What's wrong with passing in the job name as an `--extra-vars "jenkins_ci_job=ci1"` alongside whatever provides those inventory files to ansible?

Comment: Unless it is impractical to do, I would define the jenkins_ci_job as a variable within each inventory file (add a `[all:vars]` section in your inventory file and define beneath).

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel, Yes i could use this approach but I can't. The ansible command should be similar for all the jobs as we have around 100 jenkins jobs. I am not allowed to make any changes in ansible command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for `inventory_file`

So the actual variable would be like

```
jenkins_ci_job: "{{ 'ci1' if (inventory_file | regex_search('(ci1)') == 'ci1') else 'ci2' }}"
```